# search for an integer after a particular world in shell scripting

Tags: unix, csh

I have an input to unix shell script :

```
     -mem some_integer cmd1 cmd2
```

I want to get the integer value following the word "-mem". also i want to then remove both and append a new string using value of some_integer.
my output should be like 
          `cmd1 cmd2 -new_flag_some_ineteger_some_unit`

i have tried sed/awk but failed

Thanks
Ruchi

Answer (score 0):

Use $2 to pick out the second command line argument.

Use shift to discard the command line arguments after you have stored them.

Like so:

```
N=$2
export N
shift
shift
echo $* -${N}
```